# Server requested authentication method unknown to the client [mysql_old_password]

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin, remote, errors

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [mysql_old_password]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

I get the error above while trying to connect to my MySQL database server on Hostgator, using a `PHP` script on my local server. I understand it's a password hashing issue usually between pre MySQL 4.1 and MySQL 4.1+.

I've changed my local server to use the old_password following the instruction I found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33447/connect-error-2054-mysql-old-password-issue-still-not-solved).

After changing it to 16 bit hash, I still can not connect, and the error message remains the same. And more so, I can no longer login to `phpmyadmin`. I'm using `XAMPP` on windows. Please any suggestions on how to solve these problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you did this changes to the MySQL side, your only other option is to downgrade PHP.

Other links support this:

- [StackOverflow : MySQL PHP incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1340538/491757)
- [ServerFault : mysql_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [mysql_old_password] in](https://serverfault.com/a/385383/69271)
- Another Blog : http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/12188/notice-array-to-string-conversion-for-check-boxes/p1
- I just posted an update to my answer you referred to : [Connect Error (2054) - mysql_old_password issue still not solved](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33447/connect-error-2054-mysql-old-password-issue-still-not-solved/33508#33508).

Comment: Downgrading PHP solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error, trying to debug locally some application that connects to remote DBs.
When using php < 5.3, everything worked. 
When using php 5.3 or greater, error shows up.

After hours spent reading and tweaking, i realized this only occurred when connecting as a certain user.
All databases i use have new password length (41).

I changed the password for that user, and everything worked fine, even after changing it again to the previous value.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Changing the password, even setting it to the old password and restarting the mysql server did for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Changed the user's password to the existing password and it works now. Fortunately didn't have to restart mysql as this is a shared server.